# About generators and relations

Tags: group-theory, group-presentation

Let $G$ be the planar group generated by rotations of $2\pi /3$ about the three vertexes of a equilateral triangle, so there's a surjective homomorphism from $\langle x,y,z\mid x^3,y^3,z^3,xyz\rangle$ to $G$, but then is there a efficient way to determine if it's an isomorphism?

Thank you very much.

Comment: Well, yes, it is an isomorphism. You could see [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triangle_group#The_Euclidean_case) for information and references.  Note that your group is the von Dyck group $D(3,3,3)$, and it  has index $2$ in the triangle groups $\Delta(3,3,3)$, which is generated by the reflections about the three sides of the triangle.